# Angular Dynamic Carousel Active Class

Tags: angular, slider, carousel

I have a dynamic carousel and I'm pulling images directly from a node backend. Everything is working fine except my carousel is *displaying all images **at once*** instead of in a sliding motion because only the first slider needs to be active.

```
          <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div *ngFor="let data of gallery; let i=index" class="item active">
                  <img src="{{ data }}" alt="{{ name }}">
                  <div class="container">
                      <div class="carousel-caption">

                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
```

How do I make only the first dynamic slider to have the active class in the carousel?

Comment: Did my answer below work for you?

Comment: Not really, so i used another solution. Thanks for the input though

Comment: Ok, I'm glad you got it sorted.  :)

Comment: @Dng Can you put here the link where where did you found the solution?

Answer (score 3):

I think this also help

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div *ngFor="let data of gallery; let i=index" [ngClass]="(i === 0) ? 'active' : ''">
        <img src="{{ data }}" alt="{{ name }}">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this, one simple way is to tie the class assignment to which index you wish to be active.  Perhaps something like this:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div *ngFor="let data of gallery; let i=index" [class]="(i === activeIndex) ? 'active' : 'inactive'">
        <img src="{{ data }}" alt="{{ name }}">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where activeIndex is a component variable you choose which is the index of the data item you want active.

Or for a more detailed selection process tie it to a javascript function:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div *ngFor="let data of gallery; let i=index" [class]="setClass(data, i)">
        <img src="{{ data }}" alt="{{ name }}">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And now in your component:

```
setClass(data: DataType, i: number) {
    let class: string = 'inactive';
    /* more complex choice logic to set class = 'active' */
    return class;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many way to perform dynamic carousel below code will help you to fatch data dynamically.

```
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item " [ngClass]="{active:isFirst}" *ngFor="let caroiselProduct of caroiselProducts;
        index as i;first as isFirst">
            <img src="{{caroiselProduct.img_src}}" alt="Los Angeles" width="1100px" height="400px">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>{{caroiselProduct.product_name}}</h3>
                <p>{{caroiselProduct.productsortdisc}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

component.ts file

```
    export class CarouselslideComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor() { }
  caroiselProducts=[
    {
      "img_src":"../../assets/demo1.jpg",
      "product_name":"Demo1",
      "productsortdisc": "this is caroisel discription"
    },
    {
      "img_src":"../../assets/demo1.jpg",
      "product_name":"Demo2",
      "productsortdisc": "this is caroisel discription"
    },
    {
      "img_src":"../../assets/demo1.jpg",
      "product_name":"Demo3",
      "productsortdisc": "this is caroisel discription"
    }
  ];
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```